# A technical question on spikes

Tags: hiking

I possess the spikes "Snowline Chainsen Trail" of two sizes: a small one and a large one. The small one (EU sizes ≤40) sits extremely tight on my hiking shoes "Nevada MFS 6½" (size 40 EU), the large one (EU sizes ≥40) sits ok, but if you pull the rubber with your fingers, you feel that the spike chains could be moved a very tiny bit, but not too much. I never hiked with spikes; do you have an opinion on whether any of them is any good for me?

Do you have any suggestion for a better spikes model for snow trails for EU size 40 hiking shoes, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Either should be fine providing you use them in the correct context. Their jobs are to provide extra grip in **minimal** winter conditions. If there are patches of ice and your hiking on easy ground.

If you intend on going on steep terrain and/or full winter (compacted snow, etc) then you will need at least a C1 level Crampon and B1 Boot system. Snow spikes are not an adequete replacement for a proper Crampon, ice axe system and the knowledge to use them correctly.